# How to connect tomcat to posgresql docker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, docker-compose

I`ve got 2 containers which i wanna connect to each other in docker.
I created network between them and try this connection params in my connection.xml file:

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/resto" docBase="/usr/local/exploded" antiJARlocking="true" >
<!-- If you're using Confluence 5.7 or below; change maxTotal to maxActive -->
<Resource name="jdbc/postgres" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    username="resto"
    password="resto#test"
    driverClassName="net.postgresql.Driver"
    url="jdbc:sqlserver://172.22.0.2:5432/Resto"
    maxTotal="25"
    maxIdle="10"
    validationQuery="select 1" />
</Context>
```

But every time when u rebuild it got an error like this

```
2021-12-05 14:20:46,126  INFO <        ><        >[                main](ormingJodaTimeZoneInfoProvider) Loaded joda time tzdata 2017b matching JRE version
work_dir-tomcat-1  | 2021-12-05 14:20:46,126  INFO <        ><        >[                main](             rut.TimeZoneUtils) JRE tzdata version: 2017b, joda time tzdata version: 2017b
work_dir-tomcat-1  | 2021-12-05 14:20:46,146 DEBUG <        ><        >[                main](                rui.SystemUtil) exec args: date +%H:%M
work_dir-tomcat-1  | 2021-12-05 14:20:46,207  INFO <        ><        >[                main](            r.RestoEnvironment) New data directory created: /usr/local/data
work_dir-tomcat-1  | 2021-12-05 14:20:46,290 FATAL <        ><        >[                main](        rc.RestoServiceLocator) Failed to initialize Spring context. Normalized Spring message (its useless stacktrace is in trace log):
work_dir-tomcat-1  | Error creating bean with name 'resto.localization.ResxPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer#0' defined in class path resource [spring/resto-services.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'messageSourceAccessor' while setting constructor argument;
work_dir-tomcat-1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSourceAccessor' defined in class path resource [spring/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'defaultLocaleAccessor' while setting constructor argument;
work_dir-tomcat-1  | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultLocaleAccessor' defined in class path resource [spring/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed;
work_dir-tomcat-1  | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcifs/Config
work_dir-tomcat-1  | 
work_dir-tomcat-1  | java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jcifs/Config
work_dir-tomcat-1  |   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.SharedNamedPipe.<init>(SharedNamedPipe.java:63)
work_dir-tomcat-1  |   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.createNamedPipe(JtdsConnection.java:521)
work_dir-tomcat-1  |   at net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection.<init>(JtdsConnection.java:328)
```

Can you explain me what i`m doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you get that IP from? Are your containers on the same Docker network?

Comment: Although the `Exception` doesn’t seem to be related to docker or network issues adding the docker compose file would help to fix any connection problems.

Comment: You probably already validated that your spring application starts properly without the resource configuration. Right?

Comment: The error is not related to JDBC, but the correct Postresql driver is `org.postgresql.Driver`, not `net...`.

Comment: There are many issues in these configuration excerpts (wrong driver name and wrong jdbc url for Postgres, why xml configuration with spring boot, Exception points to classpath issue) but none of these is related to networking or docker. Only the IP address in the configuration will probably cause some connection problems. But your application is currently not reaching the point where this would matter.

Comment: yep,@BoristheSpider they are on the same network. tomcat is 172.22.0.3, database is on 0.2  i tryed connect them by the name like "dir-db-name" but it dosent work. Its just my current config
ill try this and give you feedback @PiotrP.Karwasz